# panda reads 0.6 as 0.59999999999999998 - wrong decimal places

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Via panda the values in the table below are read with non existing decimal place e.g.: 0.6 is read as 0.59999999999999998 (see code below)

I would have expected to read 0.6 as 0.6.

Why is it interpreted like this and what do I have to code to get the expected behaviour?

```
ldcSc = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(basepath, 'kmod_table.csv'), skiprows=2)
ldcSc

    LDC             1        2        3
0   permanent      0.6      0.6     0.50
1   long-term      0.7      0.7     0.55
2   medium-term    0.8      0.8     0.65
3   short-term     0.9      0.9     0.70
4   instantaneous  1.1      1.1     0.90

print(ldcSc.get_value((ldcSc.LDC[ldcSc.LDC == 'permanent'].index[0]), '2'))
print(ldcSc.get_value((ldcSc.LDC[ldcSc.LDC == 'short-term'].index[0]), '1'))
print(ldcSc.get_value((ldcSc.LDC[ldcSc.LDC == 'medium-term'].index[0]), '3'))
```

prints to: 
0.6
0.9
0.65

BUT:

```
ldcSc.get_value((ldcSc.LDC[ldcSc.LDC == 'permanent'].index[0]), '2')
```

0.59999999999999998

```
ldcSc.get_value((ldcSc.LDC[ldcSc.LDC == 'short-term'].index[0]), '1')
```

0.90000000000000002

```
ldcSc.get_value((ldcSc.LDC[ldcSc.LDC == 'medium-term'].index[0]), '3')
```

0.65000000000000002

Comment: Can you represent 1/3 exactly in decimal?  That's exactly the same problem that 0.1 has in binary.

Answer (score 0):

See [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) and for further reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Short version: computers don't have enough space for truly infinite precision so decimal numbers are represented in ways that have trade-offs of speed and accuracy.

For arbitrary precision decimals in Python, you need the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) package.

Comment: thank you for the information and links.